# Parsing files as PHP with AddHandler in different environments

Tags: apache-2.2, php5

I'm now so confused with how files should be parsed as PHP with `AddHandler` in different environments.

**local server**:

Windows 7 / Apache2.2 / PHP 5.2 (`thread safe`)

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php              # does not work
AddHandler x-httpd-php52 .php            # does not work
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php  # works
```

And I just upgraded PHP to 5.3 (switched to `non thread safe`)

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php              # does not work
AddHandler x-httpd-php53 .php            # does not work
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php  # does not work <-- works on 5.2
AddHandler php5-script .php              # does not work

# AddHandler... and I'v tried some of others, none of them works
```

**web hosting**

CentOS / Apache2.2 / PHP 5.3

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php              # does not work
AddHandler x-httpd-php53 .php            # works
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php  # does not work (works prior to 5.2)
```

My questions:

1. How come `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php` no longer works on my local server when I updrage PHP to 5.3 non-thread-safe? Are there any other extra work I need to do?
2. When/where/how should `x-httpd-php`, `application/x-httpd-php`, `php-script5`, and `other types of format` be used? Are these OS / Apache version / PHP version / PHP type dependent?

## edit

OK, I'm gonna answer the first question of my own

**Running PHP as an Apache Module**

```
# httpd.conf

PHPIniDir "C:/PHP"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

**Running PHP as CGI binary**

```
# httpd.conf

ScriptAlias /PHP/ "C:/PHP/"
Action application/x-httpd-php "/PHP/php-cgi.exe"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

<Directory "C:/PHP">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I'm still waiting for someone to explain the second question.